# Why os.rename() is raising an exception in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, windows, file, errno

```
print(path)
print(dir_name+"\\"+f_parent+"_"+parts[0]+"_"+date+extension)
os.rename(path, dir_name+"\\"+f_parent+"_"+parts[0]+"_"+date+extension)
```

Lines 1 & 2 are debug and statements and these print:

```
D:\Doc\Papa\Photos\2012\2012_07_divers\CSC_3709.jpg
D:\Doc\Papa\Photos\2012\2012_07_divers\2012_07_divers_CSC_3709_2012_07_06_21_04_26.jpg
```

Line 3 raises:

```
File "D:\Doc\Papa\scripts\python\photosort\photosort.py", line 83, in rename
  os.rename(path, dir_name+"\\"+f_parent+"_"+parts[0]+"_"+date+extension)
WindowsError: [Error 183] Impossible de créer un fichier déjà existant
```

which translates to:

```
 WindowsError: [Error 183] Can not create a file that already exists
```

Comment: Looks like there already is a file with the name you want to rename the file to? Have you checked?

Comment: Well, does the file already exist?

Comment: looks like, but no file with this name :)

Comment: To make this more portable you could use os.path.join in place of patching in directory seperators yourself ('\\'). That way you don't have to worry about escaping them and things.

Comment: Salut mat j'ai deduit que tu étais français si tu veux un peu d'aide en python (en francais) hésite pas mon email et mon github est sur mon profil, je pourrais te faire découvrir les pythoniens français :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It is not too localized. It is a common problem on Windows whenever someone tries to rename a file that already exists. Here's another example of the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540241/python-os-rename-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file-already-exists

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Check; reopen vote cast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Python 3.3+ you could use [os.replace()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/os#os.replace) instead of os.rename() to overwrite the existing file and to avoid the error on Windows.

On older Python versions you could emulate `os.replace()` using ctypes module:

```
# MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING = 0x1; MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH = 0x8
ctypes.windll.kernel32.MoveFileExW(src, dst, 0x1)
```

See how [`atomicfile.atomic_rename()`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/python-atomicfile/blob/master/atomicfile.py#L21) is implemented on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Windows system error codes list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS
>
> 183 (0xB7)
>
> Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

You are trying to create a file that already exists. Delete it first or pick a different filename.

As a bonus tip: Use the `os.path.join()` function to correctly join paths:

```
os.path.join(dir_name, '{0}_{1}_{2}{3}'.format(f_parent, parts[0], date, extension))
```

I've also used [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) to create your filename.

Answer (score 0):

The name you are trying to use already belongs to something. Ie, there is already a file called:

```
D:\Doc\Papa\Photos\2012\2012_07_divers\2012_07_divers_CSC_3709_2012_07_06_21_04_26.jpg
```

Add a check to your function