# python os.rename ""cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: python, error-handling, operating-system, rename

K.. I'm just using a simple script I found here:

```
import os
from os import rename, listdir

print os.listdir(".")
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.startswith("colon-"):
        print filename
        os.rename(filename, filename[7:])
```

I need to basically take all files like colon-21.mp3 converted to 21.mp3.

But I get the error `CANNOT CREATE A FILE WHEN THAT FILE ALREADY EXISTS.`
How does one solve this? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Make sure the file doesn't already exist

Comment: But I need to rename the file colon-21.mp3 that is already present as 21.mp3 ... So it doesn't technically exist..

Comment: see [Why os.rename() is raising an exception in Pyton 2.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13025313/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That link is not really going to be helpful in this case. The reason he is having this error is because he used an incorrect index in his string slicing attempt, as explained in my answer.

Comment: @Maxwell: that is why I've posted it as a comment, not as an answer. The link shows how to avoid the exception. Think about the people who landed here from google based on the question title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
os.rename(filename, filename[7:])
```

Python indices start at 0, and the string `"colon-"` is only 6 characters long, so colon-21.mp3 will become 1.mp3 using your code. Change that line to use `filename[6:]` instead and your problem should be gone.

That said, using a hard coded string length like you are doing is not a good idea. It is error prone for exactly the reasons we have discovered here (hard coded numbers like this are often called "magic numbers" because it is difficult to tell why they are set to a given length). A superior alternative would be the following:

```
os.rename(filename, filename.split('-')[1])
```

Comment: Or we can also use `split()`, `-`, i.e. `filename.split("-")[1]`.

Comment: @Ashwini I wasn't trying to endorse the method that gran_profaci used, I was just trying to show him how his code was broken. 
I agree that using hard coded numbers is usually a bad idea. I have updated my answer to explain to gran_profaci why hard coding string lengths is bad, and included your example as a recommended alternative.